# How to add tickets under the logged in user in cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having a problem adding a ticket to whoever is logged in. With cakephp 1.3 this line works perfectly fine: `$this->data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user();` Here's the complete add action:

```
public function add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Ticket->create();
    $this->data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user(); 
    if ($this->Ticket->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ticket has been saved'));
      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ticket could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
  }

  $users = $this->Ticket->User->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

Not even the code `$this->Session->read('user_id');` works now. Well, either of the two adds the ticket but the user_id is blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you debug the return value of $this->Auth->user()? i doubt that this is actually the id but an array of keys. use pr() to find out whats actually returned.

Comment: pr($this->Auth->user('id')); returns 1 which is the right id for the current user who's logged in. Any idea why the id is not being saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->Auth->user() returns an array with various fields about the user.  I think you should replace line 4 with:

```
$this->data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

Or, you could assign the results to a variable first and then attach to the ticket:

```
$user = $this->Auth->user();
$this->data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $user['User']['id'];
```

EDIT

I see what's happening now.  You are making edits to an object and then saving the request data...so your user id never gets passed to the save.

Try this:

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Ticket->create();
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); 
    if ($this->Ticket->save($data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ticket has been saved'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The ticket could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}

$users = $this->Ticket->User->find('list');
$this->set(compact('users'));
```

}

Comment: sorry this is actually what i have $this->data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); and it doesn't work. used to work with 1.3. i forgot to add these two lines after my code above:      $users = $this->Ticket->User->find('list');
$this->set(compact('users'));

Comment: are you able to debug the output from $this->Auth->user('id');?  Is it outputting anything?  Is it possible that you are not, in fact, authenticated?  CakePHP changed the Auth module quite a bit with 2.0, so the problem may be with how you are authenticating rather than this function.

Comment: pr($this->Auth->user('id')); returns 1 which is the right id for the current user who's logged in. Any idea why the id is not being saved?

Comment: what a beauty! it works perfectly except for this line, i think you missed 'id'..$data['Ticket']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user();..thank you so much.